# sql-server one to one relational tables for different types of users

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have 2 kind of users. they all have some shared information like: username, email, password, phone,... but each kind of users has some other settings that are related to that kind of user only now I have thought of 3 ways to do it:

1. having 1 users table and having all column for all type of users (each row will have several  empty columns that are not related to that kind of user)
2. having 3 tables **users**, **usertype1**, **usertype2**. that shared settings will be saved in users table and there will be a one to one relation to usertype1 or usertype2 (based on the usertype)
3. one user table and one setting table, this is more dynamic but this has a problem that I have to use varchar type for all settings.

which one is more wiser to use? I'm concerned that in the future user types might increase too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Second option is most suitable. In addition to what you have described I would add a Column to Main_Users Table User_Type which references to a table User_Types with only two 
values

**User_Type**

```
PK_TypeID    User_Type
    1        usertype1
    2        usertype2
```

**Main_User**

Only the Columns That every user will have Like first name, Last name, Dob, UserID and anyother information that every user will have.

```
U_ID |  Column1 |  Column2  |  Column3  |  User_Type  --<-- User Type values(1,2)
                                                         -- from User_Type Table
```

**Type 1**

This will be only for the users with Type one and only column that a Type1 user will have. Make `U_ID` a foreign key referencing U_ID column in the main users table.

```
U_ID  |  Column1 |  Column2  |  Column3
```

**Type 2**

This will be only for the users with `Type Two` and only column that a Type`user will have.Make`U_ID` a foreign key referencing U_ID column in the main users table.

```
U_ID  |  Column1 |  Column2  |  Column3
```

Comment: actually this is exactly what I thought too. but everywhere I read that they say don't split a table unless you are really forced too. and this scares me, why?? why people are this much against separating tables?

Comment: It means you had a very good design in your mind then :), Dont pay attention to what "everyone is saying", follow the simple rules of database normilization. Following this design you will get your database to atleadt 3rd normal form. [Read here about database normalization](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm)

Comment: I have been a programmer for 17 years and all I know is by experience,  I learned myself and only used internet as reference, thats why sometimes when I hear something I thought that there is a scientific reason behind it that I don't know. but as you said the second option makes more sense I will go for it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would think that option 3 would be the best, and you wouldn't have to use varchar for all settings. What you'll need is a third table for lookup values as `(Setting_ID, Setting_Description)`. Use the Setting_ID in your settings table along with the value for that setting.

Comment: i didn't quiet catch how can I have for example datetime, int, bit, varchar datatypes? they all must be saved in varchar format and then convert them right?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani I have seen implementations where the settings table had a column for each data type `(Value_ID, Setting_ID, Date_Value, Int_Value, ...)` and you can store the appropriate value in the corresponding column. Other option is to use SQL_Variant datatype [link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx)

Comment: Also note that M Ali's implementation would also work in most cases, but it becomes slightly problematic if you'd like to add more settings to any user type. You would have to alter all queries in your main application related the user type to represent new settings.